# Rudin's functional analysis theorem 1.21(b)

Tags: functional-analysis

This theorem proves that any finite-dimensional subspace $Y$ of a topological vector space $X$ is closed.

take $p\in \overline Y$ and we know $p\in tV$ for some $t>0$. $V$ is a balanced neighborhood of $0$ in $X$. I am confused why $p\in\overline{Y\cap (tV)}$?

In general, $\overline A\cap B\subseteq \overline{A\cap B}$? I don't think it is true, for example:

$A=(0,1),B=[1,2]$

Comment: I looked up the proof of the theorem in my copy of Rudin and cannot find this kind of statement. In my copy Rudin claims that each linear isomorphism of $\mathbb{C}^n$ onto a subspace of $Y\subset X$ of a TVS is a homeomorphism and from this concludes that such a subset is finite dimensional since it is locally compact (referring to a previous lemma). Could you please write some more details about what you found in your copy of the book?

Comment: @Thomas, you can refer to this notes http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~razk/iWeb/My_Site/Teaching_files/TVS.pdf on the top of page 198, this is exactly the same with my version.

Comment: the footnote in page 198 says it is easy to show, but I can't figure it out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $p\notin \overline{Y\cap (tV)}$, then there is a neighborhood $U_p$ of $p$ such that

$$(U_p\cap (tV))\cap Y=U_p\cap (Y\cap (tV))\subseteq U_p\cap \overline{Y\cap (tV)}=\emptyset,$$

which is an immediate contradiction: $U_p\cap (tV)$ is a neighborhood of $p$ so it must intersect $Y$.

Comment: but we can't get $U_p\cap(Y\cap(tV))\neq \emptyset$ from $U_p\cap Y\neq \emptyset$ and  $U_p\cap tV\neq \emptyset$

Comment: @user166445: thanks. I think it's ok now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware this is an old question, and also that the OP has already been given a satisfying answer; nonetheless, I've just stumbled upon it, and I think there may be a (minor?) point deserving some closer attention (sorry in advance if my remark is stupid, if so please just delete it).

In a topological space $X$, for $Y\subset X$, $p\in X$ and $U$ a neighborhood of $p$, we have:

$$p\in \overline{Y}\implies p\in\overline{Y\cap U}.$$

In fact, if $V$ is a neighborhood of $p$, $V\cap U$ is a neighborhood of $p$ as well, so:

$$(Y\cap U)\cap V\ne \varnothing.$$

[As a consequence, if $G$ is an open set: $\overline{Y} \cap G\subset \overline{Y\cap G}$.]

If the result $p\in\overline{Y\cap tV}$ is to be obtained by following the above line of reasoning, we'd need $tV$ to be a neighborhood of $p$, i.e. $p$ to be not just an object of $tV$, but an object of its *interior*.

If Rudin here is assuming only that $t>0$ is big enough so that $p\in tV$, either he is following a different (and I guess better) line of reasoning I could not think of, or he forgot to make some (stronger but unproblematic!) assumption explicit (here it would suffice to assume that $V$ is an *open* neighborhood, or that $t>0$ is big enough to have $p$ in *the interior of* $tV$) — or is he just using some uncommon convention?, such as that a neighborhood is an open set?